# Meaning and use of ところも

Tags: grammar

I am a bit puzzled by the use of ところ and its association with も in the following sentence

> さっきの少年の態度や言動には、やや引っかかる**ところも**あるが、概ね間違ってはいないんじゃないかと結論づけていた。
>   The attitude
>   and behavior of the boy had caught on with some of the passengers and
>   they convinced themselves that the boy was right.

The dictionary entries (wwwjdic) for ところ and ところも do not give a satisfying result so I tried for 
ところが (assuming that が and も does not change too much the meaning) which gives:

> even so; however; still; whereupon; even though; nevertheless; on the
>   contrary; as a matter of fact; despite;

However, it does not seem to work either

Could you help me ?

Comment: ところ is a noun, just look it up by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ところ, which literally just means "place", can be used to describe a quality or aspect of something. This is a metaphorical extension of ところ's literal meaning as a location in space/time.

> どんな人でも良い**ところ**もあれば、悪い**ところ**もある。

Everyone has both good **qualities** and bad **qualities**.

> 彼には少し臆病なところもある。

He can be a bit of a chicken at times. (lit. He also has a slight cowardly **aspect** to him.)

> やや引っかかる**ところ**もある。

There exists, as well, **something** slightly off about (a given subject).

In the case of your example, this "given subject" in my last example refers to 「さっきの少年の態度や言動」。

As an aside, the translation you give for 引っかかる (catch on with, i.e. become popular with) is not quite how it is being used here. It is being used in the sense of [#5 here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%A3%E6%8E%9B%E3%82%8B/), as roughly: "having a sense that something's off".

Does this help you understand how ところ is being used?

Comment: yes, thank you for your very clear explaination, specially about the metaphorical extensions !