# What does mean Vる+とこ?

Tags: translation, colloquial-language, japanese-to-english, parts-of-speech, help

I was watching Terrace House and someone used Vる+とこ many times in her sentence so I was wondering what it mean.
Here is her sentence :
鼻クソほじる**とこ**、よだれ飛ばす**とこ**、あと 下ネタばっか言ってる**とこ**。

Thank you !

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75111/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42524/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2968/9831

Comment: For abbreviation of ところ into とこ: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83663/9831

Answer (score 2):

It's a shorter version of 「ところ」, and means "how".
Since we don't know who she is talking about, the translation is:

- how one picks their nose
- how one drools
- how one talks dirty things

あなたのそんな「とこ」が好き。 - I like the way you are.